# Magento Soap cart.info isn't working for all carts

Tags: node.js, magento, magento-1.9

I am having a node application and I need a few informations about a shopping cart from a magento customer. So I wrote myself a little test script to test the results of the soap api (I am using [magento](https://www.npmjs.com/package/magento) to help me communication with the soap interface).

```
var MagentoAPI = require('magento');
var magento = new MagentoAPI({
    host: '192.168.73.45',
    port: 80,
    path: '/magento/api/xmlrpc/',
    login: 'dev',
    pass: '123456'
});

magento.login(function(err, sessId) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    magento.checkoutCart.info({ quoteId: 696 }, magentoCallback);

});


function magentoCallback(err,response) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("Result: ");
    console.log(response)
}
```

This script works fine. If I use some old quote ids (which are in the database from the sample data) I get a good result, but if I use an shopping cart from an user I created, then I get the following error:

```
{
    "original": {
        "message": "Unknown XML-RPC tag 'BR'",
        "name": "Error"
    },
    "name": "Magento Error",
    "message": "An error occurred while calling cart.info"
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is a <br> tag coming back in the response which is not supported by XML without proper encoding. Install Charles or similar proxy server so you can capture the raw requests and responses and see exactly where the <br/> is coming from. My suspicion is it's from a product name or description. That's the problem and hopefully the cause identified. What version of magento is this being run against? There were issues with early versions of Magento XMLRPC such as the use of null/nil tags being returned. Might also be worth trying the V2 SOAP API instead of XMLRPC.